# what are the required functions to perform unwind segue in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, unwind-segue

I am following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2) tutorial to learn how to use and unwind segues. the code provided in that tutorial is in Swift and so far i do not have good knowledge about it. Can you please tell me the equivalent functions in objective c to the following ones that are in Swift

functions in Swift:

@IBAction func cancelToPlayersViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

@IBAction func savePlayerDetail(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

Comment: The old version of this article is still accessible and uses Objective-C for its samples; maybe this is of help to you: https://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2

Comment: @dr_barto thank you..would you please tell me how did you get it? did u just google ray wenderlich tutorials in objective c for example?

Comment: It's linked at the top of the article, "Original post by Tutorial Team member Matthijs Hollemans."